# Real Analysis Limit of a Sequence Question

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on this question (from an introductory Real Analysis textbook):

> Define a sequence $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n^2}$ exists but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ does not exist.

I've come up with a sequence for which this holds.

Define

$$
a_n =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  \sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{I}\\ 
1 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  \sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{I}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

where $n \geq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{I}$. This sequence does not converge, as $(a_n)$ flips between $0$ and $1$, depending on whether or not $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer. However, for $(a_{n^2})$, we have,

$$
a_{n^2} =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  \sqrt{n^2} \in \mathbb{I}\\ 
1 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  \sqrt{n^2} \notin \mathbb{I}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

$$
 =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  n \in \mathbb{I}\\ 
1 \; \; \;  \text{if} \; \;  n \notin \mathbb{I}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

which of course is simply a sequence of zeros and as such "converges" to zero. Have I taken the right approach? Or should I be using the limit definition to define a more general sequence for which the given conditions hold. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Looks good to me. The question asks for a sequence and you've found one. If you want to improve your answer, you can rigorously show that $a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Too many symbols. Before typing all those symbols, you had an informal idea and knew that it worked: $f(k)=1$ if $k$ is a perfect square, and $fk)=0$ otherwise. Say it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it works but you could express it simplier with 
$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 
1 & \exists k \in \mathbb{N} : k^2=n \\
0 & \text{else} \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and convincing: you needed only to "find" such a sequence, and indeed you did.  I'd simply add that to make the argument fully convincing (or, perhaps more rigorous, as it seems pretty convincing to me), it might be a good idea to *demonstrate* that it is, indeed, an example of such a sequence (i.e., explicitly prove that indeed, $\;\large a_{n^2}\;$ converges to 0).